How to migrate from th:include in Thymeleaf 3.1?
As of thymeleaf-3.1 th:include is deprecated (
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/913), so I'm trying to migrate my includes, but without success.
My goal is to having a fragment that defines a table th element with a bunch of stuff.
Now only for one single th element in the table, I want to apply a different css style (in this example: text-align:right).
This is what I had before:
home.html:
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" th:include="~{components/tableheader :: tableheader('test')}" 
        style="text-align:right"/>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>

components/tableheader.html:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
        <th scope="col" th:fragment="tableheader(text)">
            <div th:text="${text}"/>
            <!-- other stuff-->
        </th>
</html>

This is nice and gets rendered as:
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" style="text-align:right">
        <div>test</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>

BUT: th:include is deprected in latest thymeleaf version, and the recommendation is to use th:insert.
Problem: th:insert loses the extra styles applied plus inserts a ghost row, which then appears as:
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" style="text-align:right"></th>  <!-- that is the problem -->
    <th scope="col">
        <div>test</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>

So you see, the I cannot simply replace th:include. How can this be fixed?

Have you tried with th:replace (link). Instead of placing the fragment inside your tag, it will be replaced by the content.

Yes I tried also th:replace, with the same result that the style attribute is lost. Even if I wrap my statement in an outer <div style="text-align:right">

After looking at other alternatives, maybe you could move the style inside the fragment. In tableheader.html <th scope="col" th:fragment="tableheader(text, style)"><div th:style="${style}" th:text="${text}"></div>... and in home.html <th th:replace="components/tableheader :: tableheader('test', 'text-align:right')" scope="col"></th>.

So but I don't want to pass the styles all the time, only for one of the elements. Can it be optional?

So, but the problem remains: imagine I would want to add a title or alt attribute to only one of the <th> elements. For every attribute I would then have to define an optional attribute inside the fragement. That's not very lean...

Sidenote: the suggestion with optimal parameter does not work: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Cannot resolve fragment. Signature "tableheader (text,style='')" declares 2 parameters, but fragment selection specifies 1 parameters. Fragment selection does not correctly match.

Sorry about the previous code. My mistake, I hadn't touched thymeleaf for a while and I thought it would work. I saw that you fixed it, I'm glad you were able to get it out.

As a workaround of optional parameters, I came up with the following:
Fragment:
        <th scope="col" th:fragment="tableheader(text)"
                th:with="style=${style != null ? style : ''}, title=${title != null ? title : ''}"
                th:style="${style}" 
                th:title="title=${title}">
            <div th:text="${text}"/>
            <!-- other stuff-->
        </th>

Usage:
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" th:include="~{components/tableheader :: tableheader('testNoStyle'}"/>
            <th scope="col" th:include="~{components/tableheader :: tableheader(text='testWithStyle', style='text-align:right')}"/>
        </tr>

